# "Hours dragged on for eternity" or "dragged into eternity"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

What's the correct expression?

Example sentence:

> The forty-one minutes dragged **into/on for** eternity. Fortunately,
>   they passed.

(I'm open to other suggestions.)

Comment: From Google Books... [*dragged on for eternity*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22dragged+on+for+eternity%22):60 hits, [*dragged on for **an** eternity*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22dragged+on+for+an+eternity%22):151 hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Drag on" is the phrase that signifies something took a seemingly very long time, so to keep this phrase I believe it should be "dragged on for eternity"
http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/drag-on